# Alter table Alter column Performance

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a table with more than 10million rows.

We are altering its column type like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER COLUMN MY_COLUMN VARCHAR(3)
```

What would be the fastest way to do this? Alter column needs to touch EVERY  row right? Is there a way to make this faster?

According to questions and answers here, I'm thinking about, create a new table and migrate data, or create a new column with `VARCHAR(3)` and migrate only the data inside this column and drop the old column.

Obs. It's taking more than 3hrs.

Comment: What is the existing datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing Aaron Bertrand's answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10754753), he says:

> Depending on what change you are making, sometimes it can be easier to
>   take a maintenance window. During that window (where nobody should be
>   able to change the data in the table) you can:
>
> 1). drop any indexes/constraints pointing to the old column, and
>   disable triggers
>
> 2). add a new nullable column with the new data type (even if it is
>   meant to be NOT NULL)
>
> 3). update the new column setting it equal to the old column's value
>   (and you can do this in chunks of individual transactions (say,
>   affecting 10000 rows at a time using UPDATE TOP (10000) ... SET newcol
>   = oldcol WHERE newcol IS NULL) and with CHECKPOINT to avoid overrunning your log)
>
> 4). once the updates are all done, drop the old column
>
> 5). rename the new column (and add a NOT NULL constraint if
>   appropriate)
>
> 6). rebuild indexes and update statistics
>
> The key here is that it allows you to perform the update incrementally
>   in step 3, which you can't do in a single ALTER TABLE command.
>
> This assumes the column is not playing a major role in data integrity
>   - if it is involved in a bunch of foreign key relationships, there are more steps.